# Problem wit MDAC when trying to compile in VS2008 using x64 bit target platform

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, mdac

I am trying to compile an 32 bit application. I am aware of problems with it but that is why its being compiled on 64 bit version.

I am hanging at this problem.
Application uses lots of sql stuff.

In sqltypes.h file: (provided by MDAC)

```
#ifdef _WIN64
typedef INT64           SQLLEN;
typedef UINT64        SQLULEN;
typedef UINT64  SQLSETPOSIROW;
#else
  #define SQLLEN          SQLINTEGER
  #define SQLULEN         SQLUINTEGER
  #define SQLSETPOSIROW   SQLUSMALLINT
#endif
//For Backward compatibility
#ifdef WIN32
  typedef SQLULEN           SQLROWCOUNT;
  typedef SQLULEN           SQLROWSETSIZE;
  typedef SQLULEN           SQLTRANSID;
  typedef SQLLEN            SQLROWOFFSET;
#endif
```

For some reason when its compiled on 32 bit platform it works great
But when I try building it on 64 it goes berserk.

Error 61 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'SQLLEN' ..\external\microsoft sdk\include\sqltypes.h 50

It does not recognize INT64, UINT64.

Is there something I need to enable so it will work under 64 build process?
Missing some #include or #define?

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: Show which other headers you are #including.  Did you #include windows.h first?

Comment: Are you sure INT64 and UINT64 are defined?  On my system, sqltypes.h depend on another header to define them.  If your 64-bit system is finding a version of that file which doesn't have those definitions, that would explain the problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is the problem. actually at this point i am sure because once i added typedef before calling sqltypes it works

Comment: do you by any chance know how to fix it?
which file is responsible to define them?
they are defined in BaseTsd.h 
but who should call that header??

thanks

Comment: Stupid question, but you did notice that the code does not get compiled when you are running 32Bit? The #ifdef excludes this in the 32bit mode.

Would you mind editing the question to include the #else bit so we can see the difference?

Comment: i added the code for else part and win32. but the issue is that INT64 UINT64 are not being defined on time.
Somewhere I need to include that file (they are defined int BaseTsd.h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem was that somehow BaseTsd.h was not included (can't believe this is possible)

but as short fix I just included BaseTsd.h manually... i will comment on this answer if i find better solution

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
#include <windows.h>
```

It contains `BaseTsd.h` and other relevant Windows-specific definitions.